# prevent slideToggle on children li link

Tags: jquery, menu, html-lists, slidetoggle

I'm using a menu on my website, with hidden sub-menus that are supposed to slidetoglle when clicking on parent li.

Everything works fine vut I'm having troubles to prevent the sub-menu to slidetoggle when clicking on a sub-menu link.

I cannot change the html structure...

fyi I also had to prevent the link of my parent li to open using e.preventDefault();

here is a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/e6a83run/

here is my code :

```
<div class="menu-menu_header-container"><ul id="menu-menu_header" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-113" class="no_link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-113"><a href="/nous-connaitre/">Nous connaître</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-114" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-7 current_page_item menu-item-114"><a href="/pionnier-radiologie-liberale-vidi" aria-current="page">Manifeste</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-115" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-115"><a href="/nos-chiffres-cles/">Nos chiffres clés</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-116" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-116"><a href="/centres-imagerie-medicale">Nos implantations</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-117" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-117"><a href="/nous-connaitre/notre-charte/">Notre charte</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-118" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-118"><a href="/nous-connaitre/notre-gouvernance/">Gouvernance</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-119" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-119"><a href="/nous-connaitre/notre-histoire/">Notre histoire</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-140" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type_archive menu-item-object-examens menu-item-has-children menu-item-140"><a href="/examens/">Vos examens</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-141" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-examens menu-item-141"><a href="/echographie/">Échographie et doppler</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-142" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-examens menu-item-142"><a href="/irm/">IRM</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-143" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-examens menu-item-143"><a href="/mammographie/">Mammographie</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-144" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-examens menu-item-144"><a href="/osteodensitometrie/">Ostéodensitométrie</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-145" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-examens menu-item-145"><a href="/radiographie/">Radiographie</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-146" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-examens menu-item-146"><a href="/scanner/">Scanner</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

and my jquery

```
$('#menu-item-127 a').first().click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

  });
  $('#menu-item-113 a').first().click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

  });
  $('#menu-item-140 a').first().click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

  });

  $("#menu-menu_header li").not(".sub-menu li").click(function(){

    var clicked = $(this);

    if ( clicked.find(".sub-menu").length > 0 ) {

      clicked.find(".sub-menu").slideToggle(150);

      $("#menu-menu_header li").not(clicked).find(".sub-menu").slideUp(150);

    }

  });
```

can anybody help me with that ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using children() because it "only travels a single level down the DOM tree"

```
$("#menu-menu_header").children().click(function(){

var clicked = $(this);

if ( clicked.children(".sub-menu").first().length > 0 ) 
  {

  clicked.children(".sub-menu").first().slideToggle(150);

  $("#menu-menu_header").children().not(clicked).find(".sub-menu").slideUp(150);

  }

});
```

Comment: did you test it in my jsfiddle ? nothing has changed...
https://jsfiddle.net/a1ouxvk5/

Comment: it does "prevent the sub-menu to slidetoggle when clicking on a sub-menu link.", doesn t it ?

Comment: no... check the jsfiddle. when you click on a sub-menu link, the sub menu slides up

Comment: In your fiddle, when I click on a so called "submenu link", i get a "404 not found"

Comment: I know, the link is not working for sure, the adress is not correct but doesn't matter.. but when you click you can see the sub menu slideUp before the 404 not found, this is what i'm trying to prevent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191967/discussion-between-sylvain-and-mmdwc).